# Interrupt ZStream mapMPar processing

Tags: zio, zio-streams

I have the following code which, because of Excel max row limitations, is restricted to ~1million rows:

```
ZStream.unwrap(generateStreamData).mapMPar(32) {m =>
  streamDataToCsvExcel
}
```

All fairly straightforward and it works perfectly. I keep track of the number of rows streamed, and then stop writing data. However I want to interrupt all the child fibers spawned in mapMPar, something like this:

```
ZStream.unwrap(generateStreamData).interruptWhen(effect.true).mapMPar(32) {m =>
  streamDataToCsvExcel
}
```

Unfortunately the process is interrupted immediately here. I'm probably missing something obvious...

Editing the post as it needs some clarity.

My stream of data is generated by an expensive process in which data is pulled from a remote server, (this data is itself calculated by an expensive process) with *n* Fibers.
I then process the streams and then stream them out to the client.
Once the processed row count has reached ~1 million, I then need to stop pulling data from the remote server (i.e. interrupt all the Fibers) and end the process.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you are doing with `effect.true`?

Regardless of the result of `effect.true` the stream is going to be interrupted as soon as that effect completes.

Comment: so the idea was to use ZIO.when(report size > ~1000000) and then interrupt the stream - but as I mentioned it interrupts immediately

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I can come up with after your clarification. The ZIO 1.x version is a bit uglier because of the lack of `.dropRight`

Basically we can use `takeUntilM` to count the size of elements we've gotten to stop once we get to the maximum size (and then use .dropRight or the additional filter to discard the last element that would take it over the limit)

This ensures that both

- You only run `streamDataToCsvExcel` until the last possible message before hitting the size limit
- Because streams are lazy `expensiveQuery` only gets run for as many messages as you can fit within the limit (or N+1 if the last value is discarded because it would go over the limit)

```scala
import zio._
import zio.stream._

object Main extends zio.App {

  override def run(args: List[String]): URIO[zio.ZEnv, ExitCode] = {

    val expensiveQuery     = ZIO.succeed(Chunk(1, 2))
    val generateStreamData = ZIO.succeed(ZStream.repeatEffect(expensiveQuery))

    def streamDataToCsvExcel = ZIO.unit

    def count(ref: Ref[Int], size: Int): UIO[Boolean] =
      ref.updateAndGet(_ + size).map(_ > 10)

    for {
      counter <- Ref.make(0)
      _ <- ZStream
            .unwrap(generateStreamData)
            .takeUntilM(next => count(counter, next.size)) // Count size of messages and stop when it's reached
            .filterM(_ => counter.get.map(_ <= 10))                     // Filter last message from `takeUntilM`. Ideally should be .dropRight(1) with ZIO 2
            .mapMPar(32)(_ => streamDataToCsvExcel)
            .runDrain

    } yield ExitCode.success
  }
}
```

If relying on the laziness of streams doesn't work for your use case you can trigger an interrupt of some sort from the `takeUntilM` condition.
For example you could update the count function to

```scala
def count(ref: Ref[Int], size: Int): UIO[Boolean] =
  ref.updateAndGet(_ + size).map(_ > 10)
    .tapSome { case true => someFiber.interrupt }
```